# Data query keeps timing out

Tags: support, data-explorer

I am trying to run [an activity query for SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph) on data.stackexchange.com but it keeps timing out. Here is the error screen:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the server is just overloaded, so it times out a lot. I kept trying repeatedly and eventually the query completed and returned results.